# GDI+ error when ASHX deployed to Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, drawing

I have the following code composing an ASHX file hosted on Azure:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            int number;
            try
            {
                number = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["number"]);
            }
            catch
            {
                number = -1;
            }

            var bitmap = new Bitmap(173, 173);
            DrawImage(bitmap, number);
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
            bitmap.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            context.Response.Flush();
        }

        private void DrawImage(Bitmap bitmap, int number)
        {
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                graphics.FillRectangle(GetBrush(number), 0, 0, 173, 173);

                Font font = new Font("Segoe UI", 40f, FontStyle.Bold);
                StringFormat textFormat = new StringFormat
                                              {
                                                  Alignment = StringAlignment.Far,
                                                  LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
                                              };
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 160, 173);
                graphics.DrawString("76", font, Brushes.Black, rectangle, textFormat);

                font = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
                textFormat = new StringFormat
                                 {
                                     Alignment = StringAlignment.Near,
                                     LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near
                                 };
                rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 10, 163, 163);
                graphics.DrawString("YOUR NUMBER", font, Brushes.Black, rectangle, textFormat);
            }
        }
```

When run locally this code operates perfectly and generates the correct result.  When deployed to Azure I get the following:

> A generic error occurred in GDI+.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A
>   generic error occurred in GDI+.

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the answer to this question, or at least one of the answers to this question.

Thanks to [Rick Strahls blog entry](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Oct/19/Common-Problems-with-rendering-Bitmaps-into-ASPNET-OutputStream). While the Bitmap cloning technique was a step in the right direction (why Microsoft?) apparently when you attempt to output a PNG from an ashx you have to take special consideration.

This consideration is basically saving the Bitmap to a MemoryStream BEFORE you save it to the real location.